# Forcing SQL Server to start a query plan with a full-text index instead of another index

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to force a query that is using a CONTAINS statement to use a full-text index as its starting point in the query plan, rather than another index. The usual WITH (INDEX(xxx)) syntax doesn't seem to work.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT f.Bar FROM Foo f
INNER JOIN Baz b ON b.FooId = f.Id
WHERE CONTAINS(f.SearchData, @p0)
ORDER BY f.Date
```

The query plan is incorrectly scanning the index on the Date column, rather than starting with the full-text search on the SearchData column.